# Using Drools drl file with common functions in 2 separate kbase/ksessions

Tags: drools

using Drools 6.2.0.Final we have a rules project with 2 separate kbases and ksessions configured like this in the kmodule.xml:

```
<kbase name="kbase1"
      packages="foo.bar.package1">
    <ksession name="ksession1" type="stateless" />
</kbase>

<kbase name="kbase2"
        packages="foo.bar.package2">
  <ksession name="ksession2" type="stateless" />
</kbase>
```

In each of these packages we have a number of .drl files that contain some business rules.
In addition to those each package contains a .drl containing functions that are called from the business rules files, e.g. package1-functions.drl and package2-functions.drl.
Since the content of these 2 function files is identical we are thinking about creating a "common" package and have only one copy of the functions file.

However, we have not managed to get our rules to work with the functions being in a separate package.

This is how we configured our kmodule.xml:

```
<kbase name="common"
    packages="foo.bar.common"/>

<kbase name="kbase1" includes="common"
    packages="foo.bar.package1">
    <ksession name="ksession1" type="stateless" />
</kbase>

<kbase name="kbase2" includes="common"
       packages="foo.bar.package2">
    <ksession name="ksession2" type="stateless" />
</kbase>
```

Another way we tried was without a "common" kbase but adding the common package to the "packages" attribute in kbase1 and kbase2.

Is it possible to use a common package within 2 other kbases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way a DRL function can be used from another DRL package.

It is possible to have one or more functions on a separate DRL file, and they can be used in any DRL file that is in the same DRL package.

Perhaps you are overrating the importance of DRL packages - you won't have any problems if all DRL files are in the same DRL package.

Alternatively, consider the use of Java static methods.

Comment: Thanks for the response. From my research I already expected that it won't be possible. The reason for having separate packages in our case is that we have a set of business rules for one customer segment an another for another customer segment which we want to treat separately. I think we will go for putting our function code in a Java class.

Comment: For  different "customer segments" you might want to build different knowledge bases. The DRL files containing the rules will be different, the package can be the same, as is the package for the functions. Then, it's a matter of config mgmt to build different knowledge bases. - But going the static method/Java way is a sound alternative, especially if the function code isn't subject to change along with rule logic.