# Drools function access

Tags: java, drools

I have a .drl file which serves as a common file for functions for my various rule files.

This .drl file which holds my common functions is in package **com.sample.common**. (file: a_common.drl)

I have a rule file which is also in package **com.sample.common** and the rules execute just fine. (file: rule1.drl)

I have a rule file which is in package **com.sample.common.anotherpackage** and the rules fail due to the function call not being available. (file: rule2.drl)

If I have read the various posts on this subject correctly, there is no easy way to make both of my rule files ( *rule1.drl & rule2.drl* ) access the common rule file *a_common.drl* unless I change the package name of rule2.drl to **com.sample.common**...

I am aware that I could do something by adjusting Java code outside of the .drl files; however, in my case I need to stick to working with functions in .drl files.

File: **a_common.drl**

```
package com.sample.common

function boolean getFirstX(String string, int x){
    ...somecode
    return (string != null);
}

function boolean getNextX(String string, int x){
    ...somecode
    return (string != null);
}
```

File: **rule1.drl** ( function getFirstX works fine )

```
package com.sample.common

rule "Hello World"
    
    when
        
        eval( getFirstX("somevalue") )
        
    then
       ....do something

end
```

File: **rule2.drl** ( function getFirstX is not found )

```
package com.sample.common.anotherpackage

rule "Hello World"
    
    when
        
        eval( getFirstX("somevalue") )
        
    then
       ....do something

end
```

Comment: Have you tried importing getFirstX from com.sample.common?

Comment: Roddy ...I did try "import.function com.sample.common.getFirstX;" in rule2.drl ... the error says "...Only a type can be imported. com.sample.common.getFirstX resolves to a package..."

Comment: Historically you couldn't call a function from a different package (see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29559528/419705)); I don't think anything has changed since then. The official documentation is ambiguous enough on this point that I can see where some confusion might arise, but I've been going back through the release notes and don't see any mention of this support being added.

Comment: Agreed ...shame it's not like "real" java where we can just import a package

Comment: Honestly the recommended way to do this is to use Java and just import your Java helper functions regardless.

Comment: Is is good practice to define the Java Helper class and associated public methods as static or does is matter ?

Comment: Doesn't matter, you can import a class and new it up if you want but that'd be a bit odd. The normal way is a class full of static methods.